# Loading different component in a project when clicked on generic tile similar concept of launchpad in openUi5

Tags: sapui5

we are creating an open ui5 project, and want to create a similar launchpad concept of Fiori Launchpad, So i have create a project in which i have created a Generic Tile page where all the tiles are loaded. On click of tile i want to load specific Modules only. For Example i have a tile name Employee List( for this there is a seperate ui5 Project which is in some Folder) on click of tile i should be able to load the Module from the given path and at the same time i should be able to change the Navigation path on URL(Like http://somehostname:port/#/EmployeeList-display).

I m able to load the module by jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("employeeList", "and Path"); but i m not able to change the URL.

```
jQuery.sap.registerModulePath("componentName", path);
//setting the url path
var _component = new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
            height: "100%",
            name: componentName,
            async: true
        });
```

when i run this project i m able to load the project and navigate to new page but URL is not getting updated. I want to update the URL so that when back button is pressed it should come back to previous page.

Comment: Is any solution for this Question?

Comment: Did You tried setHash method? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.core.routing.HashChangerBase/methods/setHash

Comment: If you really want to go down this path, I recommend reversing that logic - change the hash and based on that, change the component. If you change the component and then try to fix the hash, you'll have a much harder time keeping track and initialising things. You could even just use the router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by loading restringing the Routes for defined method and then NavTo method is called it solved my problems.

Comment: in component container i added a property called url. there i pass the location of the folder it got loaded. Its working now.